# outcomes and payoff in probability games

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am reading probability from AI point of view from book Artificial Intellegence A Modern approach by Russel and Norving. Below is text snippet from chapter 13.

> One argument for the axioms of probability, first stated in 1931 by
> Bruno de Finetti (and translated into English in de Finetti (1993)),
> is as follows: If an agent has some degree of belief in a proposition
> a, then the agent should be able to state odds at which it is
> indifferent to a bet for or against a. Think of it as a game between
> two agents: Agent 1 states, “my degree of belief in event a is 0.4.”
> Agent 2 is then free to choose whether to wager for or against a at
> stakes that are consistent with the stated degree of belief. That is,
> Agent 2 could choose to accept Agent 1’s bet that a will occur,
> offering $6 against Agent 1’s $4. Or Agent 2 could accept Agent 1’s
> bet that ¬a will occur, offering $4 against Agent 1’s $6. Then we
> observe the outcome of a, and whoever is right collects the money. If
> an agent’s degrees of belief do not accurately reflect the world, then
> you would expect that it would tend to lose money over the long run to
> an opposing agent whose beliefs more accurately reflect the state of
> the world.
>
> If Agent 1 expresses a set of degrees of belief that violate the
> axioms of probability theory then there is a combination of bets by
> Agent 2 that guarantees that Agent 1 will lose money every time.
>
> Below shows that if Agent 2 chooses to bet $4 on a, $3 on b, and $2 on
> ¬(a ∨ b), then Agent 1 always loses money, regardless of the outcomes
> for a and b. De Finetti’s theorem implies that no rational agent can
> have beliefs that violate the axioms of probability

[image]

My question is how we got values inf last column for example a,b column how we got -6, -7 an 2. Kindly explain.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Wrong stack? https://stats.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com is probably what you're after.

Comment: As already noted, this isn't a *Mathematica* question.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather straight forward: A bets on $\neg{a}$, $\neg{b}$, and on $a \lor b$. Accordingly, A will receive money, if these propositions are *true*—which can be seen in the table that tabulates all $2\times2$ possible results. B takes the counter position and the stakes simply map the probabilities to odds (e.g. $p(a) = 0.4 \implies 4:6$), which means A will lose 6 CU if $a$ and gain 4 if $\neg{a}$.

This simply is an example for a [Dutch book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book) as it gives a reason for consistency in beliefs: Since A believes in his probability assignments, he should be willing to engage in a bet with odds (i.e. stakes) clearly following the probability assumptions. As can be seen here, B can take a side on these bets that will allow him to always win.